# Selenium webdriver unable to translate french site via options

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to web scrape le monde news site (https://www.lemonde.fr)
and I have read the documentation and written the following code:

```
    options.add_experimental_option(
    "prefs", 
    {
        "intl.accept_languages": "en,en_US",
        "translate_whitelists": {"fr":"en"},
        "translate": {
        "enabled":"True"
        },
    }
)
```

However i am still receiving french text. I thought `options.add_argument("--headless")` this additional option might have interfered with it but I've ruled that out too.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. You need to add the following arguments:

- Using `add_argument()`

  - *`"--lang=fr"`*
- Using `add_experimental_option()`

  - *`translate_whitelists": {'en':'fr'}`*
  - *`translate":{"enabled":"true"}`*

Sample Code Block:

```
options.add_argument("--lang=fr");
options.add_experimental_option(
"prefs", 
    {
        "translate_whitelists": {'en':'fr'},
        "translate":{"enabled":"true"}
    }
)
```